# How to execute Kaggle Api commands on windows system?

Tags: python, api, scripting, kaggle

I'm referring to https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api

I tried executing the sample commands listed on the page in windows CMD and Python's IDLE. Not sure where it should be executed or how can I go to Kaggle CLI?

Eg. command: kaggle datasets list -s demographics

Windows CMD says: 'kaggle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Kaggle API has been successfully installed [using pip](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#installation) and the python install location along with the location of the *Scripts\* folder have been added into the *PATH*; the execution of *kaggle* directly within Windows command prompt (CMD) should be able.

In order to ensure Python and the folder *Scripts\* have been added into the *PATH* execute the command `WHERE python3` succeeding `WHERE kaggle`.

If any of the two commands above produce an equivalent output of *INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)* manually modify the PATH using the directions in [Excursus: Setting environment variables](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#setting-envvars) to add both python install location and location of the *Scripts\* folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Bash commands on Windows using the Bash shell, which is a little tricky to launch the first time. You can find instructions on how to do that here: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-bash-shell-command-line-windows-10

Hope that helps! :)